# range of string does not work correctly whit nsAttributeString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, ios6, cs193p

i'm trying to set a set of Nsattributestring for my primary string. the situation is this:

for example i have 3 string like this:

```
card1.contents = @"■■"; 
card2.contents = @"▲▲▲";
card3.contents = @"■■■";
```

and the last string like this:

```
matchingString = @"Matched 3 card: ▲▲▲&■■■&▲▲▲ for 80 points"
```

the matchingString value is inside a label.
i would try to find the range of substrings in a matchingString, and add an NsAttributeString for etch substring.

i'm using this code inside a loop for add the attribute to my label:

```
 [self addLableAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [SetCardGameViewController getUIColorFromColorCard:card.color alphavalue:1],
                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:[[self.matchedResulLabel.attributedText string] rangeOfString:card.contents]];
```

this code doesn't work, when i print the text from label, it don't have any attribute, i have tried to change

`[[self.matchedResulLabel.attributedText string] rangeOfString:card.contents]`

to

```
range:[[self.matchedResulLabel.attributedText string] rangeOfString:self.matchedResulLabel.text]
```

in this case it works fine, but is not what i need. So i think the problems is in the Range, but e cant fine were .

this is the code for the addLableAttributes method:

```
    - (void)addLableAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes range:(NSRange)range
{
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [self.matchedResulLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];
        [mat addAttributes:attributes range:range];
        self.matchedResulLabel.attributedText = mat;
    }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you maybe want to check whether your card.contents has values, or maybe you want to try:

```
range:NSMakeRange(0, [shape length])
```